# Programmatically setting the height of a UIView subview inside a cell of a UICollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, uiview, subview, uicollectionviewcell

Inside the reusable view of my cell, I have a UIView.

Then, I have this method in the controller

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // .. set value for CGFloat backgroundHeight

    [cell addSubview:cell.backgroundView];

    CGRect f = cell.backgroundView.frame;
    f.size.height = backgroundHeight;
    cell.backgroundView.frame = f;

}
```

But the UIView's height remains the same as specified in the Layout Rectangle.

What should I try next?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem here lies in the fact that you are attempting to use the cell's `backgroundView`.

Firstly, you cannot **add** the cell's `backgroundView` as a `subview`. You simply assign a `UIView` to it with :

```
cell.backgroundView = yourView;
```

Secondly, if you read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewCell/backgroundView), it clearly states :

> Use this property to assign a custom background view to the cell. The background view is placed behind the content view and its frame is automatically adjusted so that it fills the bounds of the cell.

This means, no matter what `frame` you try to set for the `backgroundView` it will **automatically adjust** and fill the entire cell. Now, I haven't actually tried it, but you *might* be able to override this by subclassing. Though, i'll mention here, I am unsure.

Back to your problem, if you really want a `UIView` that you can control, you will need to create a `UIView` and then add it as a `subview`. Using the cell's `backgroundView` is not the solution.

Comment: backgroundView is literally what I named the outlet of my UIView.  Are you suggesting there's a naming conflict?

Comment: Might well be. Try it with another name.

Comment: I remember once using `textLabel` as the name of a `UILabel` in a subclassed `UITableViewCell`, and it did conflict.

Answer (score 2):

It just seems like useless, what you'r approaching with the `UICollectionViewCell's` `backgroundView` .
By the Doc

> backgroundView The view that provides the background appearance.
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *backgroundView; Discussion The
>   view (if any) in this property is positioned underneath all of the
>   other content and sized automatically to fill the entire bounds of the
>   collection view. The background view does not scroll with the
>   collection view’s other content. The collection view maintains a
>   strong reference to the background view object.
>
> This property is nil by default, which displays the background color
>   of the collection view.

**the backgroundView is just nothing but the cell, so what you'r upto do is doesn't effect .** seems like directly changing the Cell's height.

> the best solution is to just ignore the backgroundView property all
>   together. Instead, make the collection view’s background clear, and
>   implement your own View; just throw a view behind the
>   collection view.

Kindly check this [blog](http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2013/11/uicollectionviews-backgroundview-property-is-horribly-broken/), this would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

> You can manage the Layout height With sizeForItemAtIndexPath

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
}
```

> ```
> here  you can manage spacing
> ```

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,0,5);
}
```

Comment: The cell has a UIView subview.  I want to manage the height of that.

Answer (score 1):

Controlling UICollectionViewCells is just the same as UITableViewCell. What you need to do is create a UICollectionViewCell subclass. These can seem confusing to start with but are really pretty simple to set up.

The first thing is to add any additional properties you might need like additional UIImageViews, UILabels etc. Now, we need to make sure all objects are instantiated but only once so this happens in

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

As well as instantiating an adding subviews to self.contentView set any global or default properties such as font, color etc. You can't set a frame relative to self.contentView yet though because self.contentView has zero size until layoutSubviews.

Now, create a method:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layout subviews];
    ...

    [self.backgroundView setFrame: myFrame]; // in this case
}
```

The [super layoutSubviews] is important to set self.contentView's frame from the delegate cell layout methods. This method is called every time the cell comes into view or changes in any way (which is often). What you need to do now is set the various frames of things based on self.contentView.frame or self.frame. Also, you can set any conditional properties like hiding icons depending on a state etc.

To answer the question, you do not need to add self.backgroundView because it is already there. What you do need to do is set the frame in layoutSubviews as above but you need a UICollectionViewCell subclass in order to do that.

To use the custom cell you just need to include your new .h file and swap UICollectionViewCell for your new classname in the

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method like:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like below, as you can not modify only height in frame you have to define new frame using CGRectMake function, after this you will also require to change the cell height also otherwise your view will be displayed in that much portion only.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // .. set value for CGFloat backgroundHeight
    [cell addSubview:cell.backgroundView];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(cell.backgroundView.frame.origin.x, cell.backgroundView.frame.origin.y, cell.backgroundView.frame.size.width, backgroundHeight);
    cell.backgroundView.frame = frame;
}
```